# Building a Chart in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, charts, express

I am trying to build a chart in oracle apex and I am getting a failed to parse sql query. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
SELECT NULL LINK,
E.EquipmentDescription LABEL, 
sum(EC.TIMECHECKEDIN - EC.TIMECHECKEDOUT) VALUE
From EQUIPMENT_CHECKOUT EC
join EQUIPMENT E on E.EQUIPMENTID = EC.EQUIPMENTID
group by E.EQUIPMENTDESCRIPTION
```

Comment: can you give me the description of the parse fail

Comment: This is all it says, and it doesn't run when I run the application.....Failed to parse SQL query!
select NULL LINK, E.EquipmentDescription LABEL, sum(EC.TIMECHECKEDIN - EC.TIMECHECKEDOUT) VALUE1 From SCHEMANUMBER1, EQUIPMENT_CHECKOUT EC join EQUIPMENT E on E.EQUIPMENTID = EC.EQUIPMENTID group by E.EquipmentDescription

Certain queries can only be executed when running your application, if your query appears syntactically correct, you can save your query without validation (see options below query source).

Comment: It seems it was having problems subtracting timestamp. I'll just turn the data type into integer for now :/